# Write Zipwith in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to write the `Zipwith` function in Haskell.

If I run it with the following values, it should return this result:

```
Prelude> zipWith (+) [10,20,30] [33,44,94]
[43,64,124]
```

My code so far is:

```
Zipwith f [] [] = []
Zipwith f [] _ = []
Zipwith f _ [] = []
Zipwith f (x:xs) (y:ys) = (f x y) : (Zipwith f xs ys)
```

However, the compiler tells me that I have multiple functions, all `Zipwith`, that don't have a data definition, but I thought having one wasn't necessary in Haskell.
Also, then it says that I have multiple declarations of f, but it is just an argument, I thought it wouldn't matter that there are multiple definitions of an argument.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Also note if you name your function `zipWith` - you have to `import qualified Prelude as P` or `import Prelude hiding (zipWith)`. Or just name your function `myZipWith`.

Comment: @epsilonhalbe True, but what would be even better IMO is to name it `zipWith'` (LYAHFGG is rubbing off on me ;)

Comment: `zipWith f [] []` isn't necessary; that case is covered by either of `[] _` or `_ []`.

Comment: @R.Monks I just updated my answer with a small change.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Haskell functions ***must*** start with a lower case. Upper case names are reserved for other stuff, like data types. In this case it would be a good idea to name your function `zipWith'`, because `'` is often used to indicate that the function is almost the same, but with a small change.

P.S.

Small critique of your code: You can remove the line `zipwith f [] [] = []` because the other lines catch this case already. If you want you can even write it like this:

```
zipwith f (x:xs) (y:ys) = f x y : zipwith f xs ys
zipwith _ _ _ = []
```

Since the first one is the only pattern you care about.

Answer (score 11):

Function names must start with a lowercase letter (or symbol). Upper-case letters are reserved for new data types. Your definition would be perfectly correct if it were named `zipWith`.

Answer (score 4):

To echo the other answers: Function names *must* start with a lowercase letter. This is not merely a coding convention; it is part of the actual language syntax. As in, it actually stops stuff compiling if you don't do this.

Other programming languages often have conventions on how you should use case, but the Haskell compiler actually uses this to decide what kind of name you're referring to. In this case, it thinks that `Zipwith` is some sort of data type, which (naturally) doesn't actually exist, which is why the compiler is confused.

Comment: I think it assumes it's a data constructor, which it's not, and then probably complains that the same variables are bound multiple times by different pattern bindings.