# How to obtain a list of those value that satisfy this condition?

Tags: haskell, algebraic-data-types, custom-data-type

Let's say I have a date type like this one:

```
type GroupNb = Int
type Code = Int
type Name = String
type Random = Int

data Group = Group GroupNb Code Name Random deriving Show
```

And I "add" some data(groups) in it.

Now, I want to get a list of all the `GroupNb` having `1` as the `Code`, and `"test"` as a `Name`.

```
groupNumbers :: [Group] -> [a]
groupNumbers (Group _ a b _) = nub[List.find (a == 1 && b == "test") [GroupNb]]
```

This solution doesn't work...  How could I do something like that ?

Comment: The function you seek is `filter`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I have understood your problem correctly, you have a list of `Group` that you want to filter based on a predicate (`code == 1 && name == "test"`). That is exactly what the [`filter`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:filter) function is for. So this is what your code looks like:

```
someTest :: Group -> Bool
someTest (Group _ code name _) = code == 1 && name == "test"

allGroupPassingTest :: [Group] -> [Group]
allGroupPassingTest g = filter someTest g
```

The helper method `someTest` is the predicate that `filter` is using.

Your original code was quite broken, [because in haskell functions **must** start with a lower case](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35588785/4683264). You're equality test was also broken, because `=` is for assignment, not testing equality (you're looking for `==`). I have no idea what the square brackets are doing in here `nub[List.find (a = 1 && b = "test") [GroupNb]]`. The only use of square brackets (to my knowledge) is to represent a list, or a list type. `[GroupNb]` looks like you are trying to cast your list to this type, but the way to cast is using `statement :: TypeCast`. `List.find (a = 1 && b = "test")` is almost right, but it `(a = 1 && b = "test")` should be written as a lambda like this `(\(Group _ code name _) -> code == 1 && name == "test")`.

```
GroupNumbers :: Group -> [a]
GroupNumbers (Group _ a b _) = nub[List.find (a = 1 && b = "test") [GroupNb]]
```

Comment: Thank you for all this feedback ! But I am trying to return a list containing all the GroupNb(only the GroupNb, no duplicate) that would be included in the result you would get using your solution.

Comment: Filter doesn't remove the duplicates (but `nub` does). Filter only removes the elements from a list that don't pass the test (i.e. the predicate returns false for that element).

Comment: Thanks, but would you know how I can make a list of all the GroupNb included  in the resulting [Group]?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: [Clearer example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35966088/haskell-datatype-create-list)