# How to extract a list of fields from a list of a given data type?

Tags: list, haskell, algebraic-data-types

If I have defined a datatype with, let's say, 5 attributes. How would I be able to create a list of one of the attributes.

Ex :

```
data Person = Person name fname sexe age height

Marie, John, Jessie :: Person
Marie = Person "Marie" _ _ _
John = Person "John" _ _ _
Jessie = Person "Jessie" _ _ _
```

How can I return a list containing all the names : (`Marie`, `John`, `Jessie`)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code isn't valid Haskell.  You could have

```
data Person = Person FName LName Sexe Age Height
type FName = String
type LName = String
data Sexe = Male | Female
type Age = Int
type Height = Float

marie, john, jessie :: Person
marie = Person "Marie" "Lastname1" Female 25 165
john = Person "John" "Lastname2" Male 26 180
jessie = Person "Jessie" "Lastname3" Female 27 170
```

Then you could create a list containing the three values `marie`, `john`, and `jessie` with

```
db :: [Person]
db = [marie, john, jessie]
```

Now you can operate on this list using many built in functions like `map` and `filter`:

```
getAge :: Person -> Age
getAge (Person _ _ _ age _) = age

ages :: [Person] -> [Age]
ages people = map getAge people
```

Now if you load this into GHCi you can test this as

```
> ages db
[25, 26, 27]
```

Some things to note:

- All data types must be declared if they aren't build in.
- Declare new types with `data TypeName = ConstructorName <FieldTypes>`
- Declare type aliases with `type AliasName = ExistingType`
- Type names and constructors must start with a capital letter
- Value names must start with a lower case letter.

Comment: Thanks ! But what I want is to return a list of (marie, john, jessie)... as in a list of their firstname.. not as a list of objects.

Comment: @Caro Make a function that takes a `Person` and returns a `FName`, then use `map`.  I'll let you write it yourself given the example of `age`, it should be fairly straightforward.

Answer (score 2):

You can `map` over the list with a function that extracts the name:

```
map (\ (Person name _ _ _ _) -> name) people
```

And if your data type is defined as a record, like this:

```
data Person = Person
  { personName, personFName, personSex :: String
  , personAge, personHeight :: Int
  }
```

Then you can simply say `map personName people`.